# Failed to resolve Android Library Bintray JCenter

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, bintray

I created an Android Library and upload to bintray.com

https://bintray.com/vsay01/maven/androidcommonutils

It was link to JCenter as well.

In my gradle of the app, I added:

```
implementation 'com.vsay01.utils:androidcommonutils:1.0.0'
```

In my gradle of the project, I added:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/vsay01/maven'
        }
    }
}
```

When sync the gradle, I got the error:

```
Failed to resolve: androidcommonutils
```

Could anyone point out what could be wrong for this ?

[EDITED]
Library information:

```
ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'androidcommonutils'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.vsay01.utils'
    libraryName = 'AndroidCommonUtils'
    artifact = 'androidcommonutils'

    libraryDescription = 'Collections of practical Android common utils classes for developer'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/vsay01/AndroidCommonUtils'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/vsay01/AndroidCommonUtils.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.0.0'

    developerId = 'vsay01'
    developerName = 'Vortana Say'
    developerEmail = 'sayvortana.itc@gmail.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under the *artifactId* [`androidcommonutils`](https://dl.bintray.com/vsay01/maven/com/vsay01/utils/androidcommonutils/1.0.0/) you have only the `.pom` file and missing the artifacts.
Your artifacts are located under [`androidutilslibrary`](https://dl.bintray.com/vsay01/maven/com/vsay01/utils/androidutilslibrary/).

You need to move the pom or the artifacts to use the correct `artifactId`.

Comment: Thanks @Royg. This is my first android library. Could you give more explanation or point out why this issue happened? Is it because of configuration I edited and provide the gradle.

Comment: This is a result of having `artifact` !== Your library's **module** name (in your case - `androidcommonutils` is the artifact name and `androidutilslibrary` is the module name defined in your gradle). This is the technical way in which to perform what [Royg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3719024/royg) suggested - moving the pom and the artifact to reside together.